# Целесообразность использования полубайтовых строк при размере словаря N <=16

Tags: delphi, ассемблер, binary, cpu, биоинформатика

Геном человека, да, и вообще, геномика. Работа со строками высокой вырожденности (размер словаря не превышает 16 членов). Весьма интересно попытаться сэкономить память и сделать замену:

```
'A' -> 0000
'C' -> 0001 
и т.д
```

. 
А строки представлять в виде array of bytes.
Но тогда, скорее всего, придётся переписывать функции поиска, скорее всего, на ассеммблере. Будет ли стоить игра свеч?

Comment: будет... А чтобы не переписывать всё - используйте наглый хак. Где раньше был обычный символ - упихивайте 2 символа (16 бит первый и 16 бит второй). Поиск даже не сломается почти) А вообще не видя профиля нагрузки без профайлера и не зная задачи ответить нельзя.

Comment: Как я понял, автор это и предлагал. А вот обычные функции поиска не очень подойдут  - их можно использовать, конечно, но подстроку придётся формировать, а это муторно уже даже всего лишь для 4х-буквенного алфавита. Хотя надо смотреть Но функции нечеткого поиска в любом случае придётся переписать.

Comment: Может не совсем по теме но... Вы про префиксные деревья знаете?

Comment: Сталкивался. Но в биоинформатике, ЕМНИП, никогда не применял. Есть пример?

Comment: С биоинформатикой не работал. Применял для распознавания ключевых слов в лексере. Но пока читал про эти деревья, попадались отсылки что они популярны в сфере обработки днк. В частности есть алгоритмы для сжатия этих деревьев.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Соблазн велик :) Но явный выигрыш виден только в том, чтобы сэкономить память, где будут храниться наши строки. Подозреваю, что при нынешней цене на ОЗУ, плюс к тому, что большинство мат. плат поддерживают, как минимум, 16 гигабайта оперативки (де факто, минимальный стандарт для биоинформатических задач на сегодня), это не так уж актуально. Да, сэкономите в два раза (в тяжелых случаях, если вдруг кто-то по ошибке решил использовать WideString - в 4 :) ). Это в 2006 году, когда я написал первый в мире (ну, надо же похвастаться :)) полный полнофункциональный тритер для генома человека, который работал на обычном PC, экономия памяти была очень актуальна. Но уже 11 лет прошло.
А вот по скорости, скорее всего, проиграете. Причём не на функциях поиска, а на конвертировании string -> array, которое съест весь выигрыш. Ведь и сиквенсы и SAM/VCF/BED, - все используют обычный строковый тип. Разве что свои данные будете хранить уже в половинном размере, и их загрузка/сохранение тоже чуть сэкономят время.

Однако, плюсы всё же могут быть:

- Работа на слабых машинах. Много таких стоят на приборах, иногда надо что-то быстро обработать
- Конвертация один
  раз, а работы затем много. Если функции оптимизировать, глядишь, и
  будет выигрыш.
- Работа с очень большими данными. Как минимум, геном
  человека, причём перекрестное масштабируемое исследование. Или вообще
  геномы хвойных деревьев.

Функции поиска придётся переписывать. Могу привести в качестве примера несколько своих, которые использовали. Написаны для 64-битных приложений, но младшие могут быть переписаны и для 32-разрядных систем.

Более того, я использовал вот такое представление псевдо-строки:

```
type
  ByteArray = array of byte;
  TBA = record
     oddity:integer;
     ar:ByteArray;
  end;
```

Почему так? oddity нужно для того, чтобы задать - чётное количество в строке или нет. Либо придётся жертвовать одним членом алфавита и конец строки помечать нулевым полубайтом (или байтом) - аналог Z-строк. Либо первые ? байтов будут задавать длину такой строки. Оба этих варианта, на мой взгляд, проиграют использованию записи.

Вот, к примеру, две функции поиска трёхбуквенных подстрок:

```
function Search3Values(ba:ByteArray; mask:word):int64; overload;
asm
   push rbx
   mov bx, dx // дублируем маску
   rol dx, 4  // и сразу же её сдвигаем
   mov r9,[rcx-8] // сохраняем количество байтов в байтовом массиве
@loop:
   mov ax, [rcx]  // загрузка байтов
   push ax  // сохраняем для ещё одной проверки
   push bx
   or ax, $F000 // накладываем маску
   and bx, ax
   cmp bx, ax // сравниваем
   pop bx
   pop ax // восстанавливаем AX
   jne @not_found
   shl r10, 1 // умножаем на 2, указывая адрес в "полубайтах"
   mov rax, r10
   pop rbx
   ret
@not_found:
   or ax, $000F
   push dx
   and dx, ax
   cmp dx, ax
   pop dx
   jne @not_found_ror
   shl r10, 1 // умножаем на 2, указывая адрес в "полубайтах"
   inc r10  // и увеличиваем на 1 - был сдвиг
   mov rax, r10
   pop rbx
   ret
@not_found_ror:
   inc rcx
   inc r10
   cmp r10, r9
   jne @loop
@not_found_global:
   mov rax, - 1 // возвращаем "-1": ничего не нашли
   pop rbx
   ret

end;

function Search3Values(ba:ByteArray; mask:word; pos:integer):int64; overload;
asm
   push rbx
   mov bx, dx // дублируем маску
   rol dx, 4  // и сразу же её сдвигаем
//   xor r10,r10
   mov r9,[rcx-8] // сохраняем количество байтов в байтовом массиве
   mov r10, r8
   shr r10,1 // делим пополам
   dec r9
   sub r9, r10 // сколько осталось проверять
   js  @not_found_global
   jz  @not_found_global
   mov r9,[rcx-8]
   add rcx, r10 // перемещаем указатель
   dec r9 //мы сравниваем байты со словом с шагом в один байт, таких сравнений будет length - 1, поэтому сразу уменьшаем счётчик на 1
   mov ax, [rcx]  // загрузка байтов
   bt r8w,0  // проверка на чётность
   jc @not_found
@loop:
   mov ax, [rcx]  // загрузка байтов
   push ax  // сохраняем для ещё одной проверки
   push bx
   or ax, $F000 // накладываем маску
   and bx, ax
   cmp bx, ax // сравниваем
   pop bx
   pop ax // восстанавливаем AX
   jne @not_found
   shl r10, 1 // умножаем на 2, указывая адрес в "полубайтах"
   mov rax, r10
   pop rbx
   ret
@not_found:
   or ax, $000F
   push dx
   and dx, ax
   cmp dx, ax
   pop dx
   jne @not_found_ror
   shl r10, 1 // умножаем на 2, указывая адрес в "полубайтах"
   inc r10  // и увеличиваем на 1 - был сдвиг
   mov rax, r10
   pop rbx
   ret
@not_found_ror:
   inc rcx
   inc r10
   cmp r10, r9
   jne @loop
@not_found_global:
   mov rax, - 1 // возвращаем "-1": ничего не нашли
   pop rbx
   ret
end;
```

А вот - для поиска семибуквенной подстроки:

```
function Search7Values(ba:ByteArray; mask:cardinal; pos:integer):int64; overload;
asm
   push rbx
   xor rax,rax
   mov ebx, edx // дублируем маску
   rol edx, 4  // и сразу же её сдвигаем
//   xor r10,r10
   mov r9,[rcx-8] // сохраняем количество байтов в байтовом массиве
   mov r10, r8
   shr r10,1 // делим пополам
   sub r9, r10 // сколько осталось проверять
   sub r9, 3
   js  @not_found_global
   jz  @not_found_global
   mov r9,[rcx-8]
   add rcx, r10 // перемещаем указатель
   sub r9,3 //мы сравниваем байты со словом с шагом в одно слово, таких сравнений будет length - 3, поэтому сразу уменьшаем счётчик на 3
   mov eax, [rcx]  // загрузка байтов
   bt r8w,0  // проверка на чётность
   jc @not_found
@loop:
   mov eax, [rcx]  // загрузка байтов
   push rax  // сохраняем для ещё одной проверки
   push rbx
   or eax, $F0000000
   and ebx, eax
   cmp eax, ebx
   pop rbx
   pop rax // восстанавливаем AX
   jne @not_found
   shl r10, 1 // умножаем на 2, указывая адрес в "полубайтах"
   mov rax, r10
   pop rbx
   ret
@not_found:
   push rax
   push rdx
   or eax, $0000000F
   and edx, eax
   cmp eax, edx
   pop rdx
   pop rax
   jne @not_found_ror
   shl r10, 1 // умножаем на 2, указывая адрес в "полубайтах"
   inc r10  // и увеличиваем на 1 - был сдвиг
   mov rax, r10
   pop rbx
   ret
@not_found_ror:
   inc rcx
   inc r10
   cmp r10, r9
   jl @loop
@not_found_global:
   mov rax, - 1 // возвращаем "-1": ничего не нашли
   pop rbx
   ret
end;
```

Принцип банален: при поиске длинных подстрок, строка, в зависимости от длины, билась на комбинации более мелких и использовались соответствующие функции. Для очень длинных подстрок (и не сильно старых процессоров) хорошо показали себя   **movdqu/vmovdqu** (SSE2/AVX) в комплекте с **psrlw** (сдвиг в регистре на 4 бита): при использовании разных регистров профилировщик показывал почти удвоенное ускорение.
А вообще, по хорошему, надо писать под такие вещи функции нечеткого поиска. В теории, вот где можно откопать золотую жилу :)

**Update 1**

Как ни странно, всё новое - это хорошо забытое старое :) Сейчас, оптимизируя кое-какие библиотеки под ядра Zen (новый парк счётных машин - AMD Ryzen), обратили внимание, что стандартные данные при работе с генами, если их использовать в полубайтовом формате, очень хорошо "влезают" в кэш ядра Zen. Скорость обработки вырастает очень серьезно.

Comment: Ого! Попробую прикинуть. Где вы справку по ассемблерным кодам беретё?

Comment: Иногда просто гуглю :) Но обычно на столе фирменные "кирпичи" от Intel (когда-то сертифицировался, так до сих пор присылают документацию бесплатно :) ) и распечатки справочников AMD. Всё это можно скачать с сайтов поддержки компаний-производителей CPU.

Comment: к Update1: у нас пока нет Zen, хотя сейчас рассматриваем покупку 2х новых машин для обработки. Считаете, они лучшие?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Что значит "лучшие"? Каждый решает сам. Для нас они наилучшие по соотношению количество*производительность/цена - для наших задач.