# Нагруженные деревья в биоинформатике. Часть 2. Нечеткий поиск

Tags: java, c++, delphi, биоинформатика, нечеткий-поиск

Непосредственно связан с темой [Нагруженные деревья в биоинформатике. Часть 1. Точный поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753397/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-1-%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA). В ней определён ряд понятий, на которые я буду ссылаться, повторяться не буду, чтобы не увеличивать размер текста.

В предыдущей части мы рассмотрели точный поиск и его возможности с использованием нагруженных деревьев. Однако, львиная доля задач в биоинформатике приходится на нечёткий поиск, то есть поиск таких областей в референсе (для краткости будем называть их вхождениями), с которыми паттерн имеет максимальное сходство.

**Варианты различий паттерна и вхождения** ограничены:

**Замена**: один нуклеотид заменен на другой, т.е. одна буква заменена на другую. Например, в референсе A, в паттерне - C, и т.п.
**Инсерция**: в паттерне "лишняя" буква по сравнению с вхождением
**Делеция**: в паттерне отсутствует буква по сравнению с вхождением
**Свисающие концы**: часть паттерна совпадает с вхождением, а конец или концы - нет.
**Штраф**: критерий различия паттерна и вхождения. Обычно представляет собой сумму штрафов за каждое различие с определенными коэффициентами, задаваемыми пользователем, например,  0.7*(количество замен) + 1*(количество делеций) + 1*(количество инсерций) + 1.1*свисающий конец.

Иллюстрация различий:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Различия могут быть множественными (несколько различий паттерна и вхождения, разделенных хотя бы одной буквой), разными (несколько вариантов различий) и повторяющимися (одно и то же различие подряд). За повторяющиеся однотипные различия штраф обычно меньше, чем за множественные.

Обычно, имеется референс и массив паттернов, которые необходимо картировать (определить координаты в референсе, где каждый паттерн будет максимально соответствовать референсу). Идеальный метод поиска должен делать следующее: для каждого паттерна определять, существуют ли точные соответствия в референсе, если нет, то найти:

- либо все возможные вхождения с наименьшим уровнем штрафа
- либо все возможные вхождения со штрафом, не превышающий указанный
- либо найти все возможные вхождения с определенными различиями

Для этого применяют алгоритмы, основанные на базе метрики (расстояния Хемминга, Левенштейна и Дамерау-Левенштейна, разные варианты Битап-алгоритма), на базе динамического программирования с подсчётом штрафов (алгоритм Смита — Ватермана, алгоритм Нидлмана — Вунша) и др. Есть также интересный алгоритм из систем сжатия (преобразование Барроуза — Уилера), который хорош для коротких референсов. Я обозначил те, которые реализовали мы сами и которые реализованы в бесплатных и коммерческих пакетах, используемых нами в повседневной работе. Много ссылок на алгоритмы приводить не буду, они хорошо гуглятся, приведу лишь одну, на мой взгляд, не очень подходящую для биоинформатики, зато очень интересную для понимания: [Нечёткий поиск в тексте и словаре на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114997/).

У всех реализованных методов есть весьма существенные недостатки:

- чем больше референс, тем хуже они работают
- все они плохо работают с делециями
- если в референсе есть несколько одинаковых вхождений для определенного паттерна, они выдают только одно, а не все

Фактически, все эти недостатки и побуждают к рассмотрению нагруженного дерева. Да, придется для каждой ветки проводить локальный нечеткий поиск, но его можно реализовать пусть даже методом перебора (скользим по ветке, рассматриваем все варианты). Зато решаем сразу все три проблемы (пусть и теряем во времени, будем использовать многопоточный подход). Но, как мы сообща показали в предыдущей части, даже для 8й хромосомы полное нагруженное дерево займёт прорву памяти, что уж говорить про геном целиком. Нужен какой-то комбинированный вариант, но какой?

Комнату с чатом для возможного обсуждения оставлю прежней: [Нагруженные деревья в биоинформатике](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69687/)