# Алгоритм сортировки большого файла с со сложностью приближенной к O(2n)

Tags: java, алгоритм, многопоточность, сортировка

Есть файл размером 1Гб который содержит FLOAT в бинарном виде, т.е. 4 байта на 1 значение. Как реализовать сортировку такого файла с применением **многопоточности** и с ограничением **RAM 128mb** и чтобы сложность алгоритма сортировки была приближена к **O(2n)**?

Comment: Сложности `O(2n)` не бывает. А по сути - пока забейте на многопоточность и попытайтесь хоть что-то сделать с ограничением памяти.

Comment: Самое то здесь - сортировка слиянием *через файлы*. Многопоточность в принципе может сыграть при сортировке разных частей, но только уже тогда, когда получаются файлы, полностью помещающиеся в память - иначе дисковые операции, скорее всего, просто сведут преимущества многопоточности на нет. Впрочем, все это надо пробовать и мерять...

Comment: Пока еще не придуман алгоритм сортировки, который бы гарантировал сложность меньше `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: Сортировку слиянием рассматривал, но не много не подходит сложность O(n log n).

Comment: @rjhdby Ну как это не придуман... Даже несколько. Только с некоторыми ограничениями.

Comment: @MBo черпак на floata-х при недостатке памяти? В теории можно но не за 2 прохода же.

Comment: @pavel Мне кажется, зря Вы интерпретируете сомнительное утверждение про сложность как два прохода. А на float и поразрядную делают (с преобразованием в зависимости от знакового бита)

Comment: Попробуйте паралельно писать в много файлов (сколько открыть сможете), в каждый числа из определенного диапазона. В идеале бы получить объем каждого файла до 128Мб, но боюсь ограничение на количество открытых файлов все испортит. Плюс будут проблемы если распределение значений далеко от равномерного и из каких то диапазовов значений будет много больше, чем из других. Потребуется дополнительное дробление. Если файлы все таки получились, читаете их по порядку и сортируете значения внутри каждого из них.

Comment: Что то вроде примененного тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/768244/194569 только там было заведомо хорошее распределение, что давало файлы примерно одинакового объема. И да, многопоточность я там вводил, но в итоге все упиралось в дисковый ввод-вывод

Comment: создаем `0xFFFFFFFF` сумматоров, в каждом будет хранится количество соответствующих чисел исходного файла. Потом восстанавливаешь. Как раз линейная скорость будет. Только это не сортировка, а что-то ближе к архивации.

Comment: rjhdby Это сортировка - подсчётом (counting sort). Только памяти немерено нужно.

Comment: Сортировка выбором (selection sort) хоть и имеет асимптотику O(n^2) (количество _сравнений_), но делает только O(n) _перемещений_ - а это весьма критично при использовании медленного устройства типа диска. Ведь в память все не лезет.

Comment: Вам надо отсортировать файл? Тогда, возможно стоит воспользоваться [bsort](https://github.com/pelotoncycle/bsort). Или сделать это требуется именно на Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Псевдокод

```
valueBytes = Float.bytes
input = new File(name = 'input')
counterBytes = minBytesToFit(ceil(input.size/valueBytes))

temp = CreateFile(name = 'temp', size = maxNumberFor(bytes = valueBytes)*counterBytes + counterBytes, fill = 0)
output = CreateFile(name = 'output', size = input.size)

for(i=0; input.size/valueBytes; i++){
    current=input.readNumber(offset = i*valueBytes, count = valueBytes)
    currentTemp = temp.readNumber(offset = current, count = counterBytes)
    currentTemp++
    temp.writeNumber(offset = current, count = counterBytes, value = currentTemp)
}

for(i=0; temp.size/counterBytes; i++){
    current = temp.readNumber(offset = i*counterBytes, count = counterBytes)
    out.append(value = i, count = current, blockSize = valueBytes)
}
```

PS Как заметил @MBo - это сортировка подсчетом. Только вместо памяти используется диск.

Comment: файл `temp` же должен быть 2^(Float.bytes * 8) - примерно 4.2Гб!

Comment: @dgzargo файл `temp` должен быть `"максимальное значение" * "размер счетчика"`. Где `максимальное значение` - это 4 байта по `FF`, т.е. 0xFFFFFFFF, а размер счетчика - это количество байт, в которые гарантированно поместится число `"размер файла"/"размер значения"`

Comment: @dgzargo у меня вышло 15ГБ, хотя может где и облажался при расчете. Ну а что вы хотели при таких вводных? :) Зато сложность линейная и в заявленную память укладывается.

Comment: немного не ясно: "размер значения" == 4 байта по FF, т.е. 0xFFFFFFFF ?

Comment: @dgzargo по сути нам надо иметь ячейку счетчик для каждого возможного значения. т.е. от 0 до FFFFFFFF(длина значения 4 байта)

Comment: поправка:файл `temp` же должен быть  `4Б * 2^(Float.bytes * 8)`;    `Float.bytes * 8` - размер в битах типа `float`;  `2^(Float.bytes * 8)` - количество вариантов значений типа `float`

Comment: @dgzargo а что такое `2^(Float.bytes * 8)` как не `0xFFFFFFFF+1`? ;)