# Самый быстрый способ объединить два списка без дубликатов

Tags: c#, linq, производительность

Продолжение этой темы [Ошибка при чтении большого файла в память](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1231386/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c/1231449#1231449)

Есть 2 файла. Размером по 10гиг. Длина строк одинаковая. 10 символов. Стоит задача - объединить и удалить дубли. Подскажите самый производительный способ?

```
IEnumerable<string> l1 = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
IEnumerable<string> l2 = File.ReadAllLines(textBox2.Text);
l1.Concat(l2);
var l3 = l1.Distinct().ToList();
```

Решение в лоб работает, но очень медленно

Comment: Можно попробовать отсортировать и проходиться одновременно по двум спискам, но не уверен что быстрее будет и сколько это доп памяти займёт. Или строить символьное дерево, постепенно заполняя слова при добавлении из листов (если в дереве уже есть путь из 10 конкретных символов, то такое слово уже добавлено). Таким образом каждая вставка будет за констрантное время.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1174712/373567 - вдруг поможет

Comment: Ваше решение влоб вообще не работает, т.к. вы не сохраняете результат Concat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый быстрый - использовать HashSet

```
var ret = new HashSet<string>();
foreach(var line in File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text)) ret.Add(line);
foreach(var line in File.ReadAllLines(textBox2.Text)) ret.Add(line);
```

Или если файлы сильно большие не не лезут в память

```
var ret = new HashSet<string>();
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(textBox1.Text)) ret.Add(line);
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(textBox2.Text)) ret.Add(line);
```

Comment: Файлы не лезут в память, то с большой вероятностью и после удаления дубликатов не влезут, наверное?

Comment: @АндрейNOP не понял вашей мысли. В первом варианте все данные сначала заливаются в память (включая дубликаты), во втором только уникальные значения в памяти.

Comment: @АндрейNOP про вероятность дубликатов вопрос надо автору адресовать :)

Comment: Кстати, `ReadLines()` отличная штука, вот только надо узнать, как долго она держит файл открытым, пока не доитерируешься до `false` в энумераторе наверное. Надо глянуть сорцы .NET.

Comment: Причем вероятность этого большая, т.к 10 ГБ это 10^9 строк по десять символов, а всего различных строк, длиной 10, даже если брать только ascii, существует более 10^21. Т.е. могут вообще все строки различные быть, вы загрузите в память 20 ГБ данных

Comment: @aepot в данном случае ReadLines отработает как надо. Я только не уверен в величине буфера тут (иногда можно выставить буфер побольше и чтение будет побыстрее), но вцелом код ок

Comment: Ну и Distinct использует HashSet внутри, так что ваше решение почти не отличается от авторского. Ну за исключением использования ReadLines вместо ReadAllLines

Comment: @АндрейNOP может быть, а может и не быть. Смысл гадать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP мое решение отличается, так как оно не держит список со всеми элементами в памяти. Конкатенация списков также занимает время. Например, если в фалах 99% данных дубликаты, то лбюбое из моих решений будет быстрей работать, чем решение в вопросе.

Comment: Конкатенация из Linq ленивая и новая строка будет проходить через нее сразу в HashSet, который в Distinct, что использовать надо ReadLines, а не загружать сразу все, это понятно

Comment: Ну т.е. автору надо просто `l1.Concat(l2).Distinct()` и использовать ReadLines

Comment: @АндрейNOP так то да, но 1) у автора l1.concat(l2) никуда не пишется 2) Все еще есть разница между кодом автора и моим ответом при наличии дубликатов

Comment: @АндрейNOP также Linq.Distinct использует самописный Set на линейном пробировании, хз насколько он отличается от классического HashSet. + list.Distinct.ToList() выделит память дважды, первый раз для внутреннего Set, второй раз для результирующего List

Comment: В моем комментарии ToList нету ;)

Comment: @АндрейNOP окау