# C# переписать строку в файле

Tags: c#

Пользователь создаёт запись в файле. Далее, если нужно, он может переписать нужную запись. Как сделать грамотно перезапись строки, чтобы не нужно было переписывать целый файл, в котором может быть тысячи строк?

Comment: Строки фиксированной длины? Или произвольные строки?

Comment: Вот для этого и придумали базы данных - чтобы не переписывать тысячи строк

Comment: В крайнем случае можно разбить большой файл по какому-то принципу на более мелкие файлы. Но переписывать всё-равно придётся, если строки произвольной длины.

Comment: строки произвольной длинны(

Comment: для строк произвольной длины вам придется перезаписывать файл. Но в чем проблема просто эти строки писать в конец файла?

Comment: задание просто такое попалось

Comment: Когда вы к кому то обращаетесь, то пишите его ник вот так @SergeiArhipenko. С текущей информацией, что вы предоставили, вам придется перезаписывать файл.

Comment: @tym32167 Понял вас! Спасибо!

Comment: Не, ну в принципе если известна максимальная длина строки, можно сделать все строки этой длины и задача сведётся к задаче с фиксированными строками. Но если файл дан уже готовый, то так не получится.

Comment: Как идентифицируется строка в файле? По номеру (id)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При условии, что строки произволной длины. Мне кажется, можно и перезаписывать, если файл не огромный. "Тысячи строк" не выглядит страшно.

Главное - стараться не читать весь файл в память для этого.

Этот метод перезапишет одну строку в файле по ее индексу.

```cs
private static void RewriteLine(string path, int lineIndex, string newValue)
{
    int i = 0;
    string tempPath = path + ".tmp";
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) // читаем
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tempPath)) // и сразу же пишем во временный файл
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (lineIndex == i)
                sw.WriteLine(newValue);
            else
                sw.WriteLine(line);
            i++;
        }
    }
    File.Delete(path); // удаляем старый файл
    File.Move(tempPath, path); // переименовываем временный файл
}
```

Должно работать очень быстро, настолько, насколько диск позволяет. Если файл нормально разбит на строки, то и памяти съест немного.

*Можно еще доработать, чтобы строка дописывалась в конец, если индекс строки больше, чем строк в исходном файле.*

```cs
RewriteLine("file.txt", 1, "New string");
```

Для того, чтобы менять данные в файле не перезаписывая файл целиком, надо либо иметь строки фиксированной длины, тогда можно будет просто по нужному смещению записать нужный текст, либо реализовывать таблицу размещения данных с поддержкой фрагментации, по подобию (любой) файловой системы.

Comment: Если уж заморачиваться со скоростью, то я бы добавил буфер для чтения и записи.

Comment: @tym32167 оно там с дефолтными параметрами норм буферизуется, в том числе операционной системой. Я проверял, от игры с буферами мало что меняется. А если SSD, то вообще ничего не меняется. На таком уровне задачи, прикручивание буфера не даст примерно ничего, кроме дополнительного кода. :)

Comment: Если файлик в пару магабайт, то да, толку нет. Я когда то игрался с буфером файликов [побольше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/768072/179763), там прирост был прямо очень ощутимый, с нескольких часов до получаса уменьшил время обработки.