# Как переписать данные файла

Tags: c#

Формат содержимого файла: дата,фамилия сотрудника,кол-во часов роботы,проделанная работа.

Пример: 03.11.2020,Иванов,8,помыл полы.

В методе происходит переписывание отчёта, в данном случае нужно переписать только кол-во часов, и вот я встал в ступор.

Как переписать, если я не знаю заранее сколько часов сотрудник проделал работы в определённый день?

```
    private void rewriteRep(User user, DateTime date, int hours)
    {
        if (!Helper.CheckEmployeeExists(user))
            throw new ArgumentException("Ошибка... Такого пользователя не существует!",nameof(user));

        if (!Helper.IsReportWritten(user, date))
            throw new ArgumentException($"Отчёта за {date:d} не существует!", nameof(date));

        string str = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(Helper.RolePathParser(user)))
        {
            str = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        str = str.Replace(string.Format($"{date:d},{user.LastName}, /* как?! */"),
                           string.Format($"{date:d},{user.LastName},{hours}")); // проблемное место

        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(Helper.RolePathParser(user)))
        {
            file.Write(str);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну есть разные методы. Например, побить строку по запятым и проверять часть этих кусочков, которые известны. Либо через `regexp` проверять, что это та строка.

Comment: Но в любом случае построчно обрабатывать и проверять надо, по-другому вряд ли выйдет.

Comment: [Оно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199596/373567)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void rewritingRepProcess(User user, DateTime date, int hours)
    {
        string path = Helper.RolePathParser(user);

        string line = "";
        string temp = "";
        string content = "";

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(string.Format($"{date:d}")) && line.Contains(user.LastName))
                {
                    temp = line;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        var item = temp.Split(',');
        string ad = string.Format($"{item[0]},{item[1]},{hours},{item[3]}");

        content = content.Replace(temp, ad);

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
            writer.Write(content);
    }
```